# Making List of Lists Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

i am trying to get pairs of coords and i have got this function that outputs: [9,0,9,1]....... etc

```
addVal :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
 addVal i [] = []
 addVal i (x:xs) =  i:x : addVal i xs
```

but i want the output to be a list of lists : [[9,0],[9,1]]

```
addVal :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
addVal i [] = [[]]
```

how do i get it so the it will make each pair a list so i i can use it with my other functions to get the smallest of the pairs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, instead of `i:x` you have to use `[i,x]`. Note that you want the elements in the new list, so you create `[i,x]` and pass it up.

```
addVal :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
addVal i [] = []
addVal i (x:xs) =  [i,x] : addVal i xs
```

Demo in ghci

```
λ> addVal 9 [1,2]
[[9,1],[9,2]]
```

Comment: thanks i know it was something small but just didnt know it in haskell

Comment: Note that this is a map : `addVal i = map (\x -> [i,x])`. I don't know if I would even write a function for this...

Comment: im trying to convert my java code over to haskell for i can compare them so trying to do it as literal at possible but thanks for the help